# recursive operation on trigger while trying to update records

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex

I have Case object in salesforce. i am trying to submit RMA to submit and getting error .
Error is
CCS_AS400_Integration: execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, CCS_AS400_Line_Import: execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 500Nu000003yy4SIAQ; first error: SELF_REFERENCE_FROM_TRIGGER, Object (id = 500Nu000003yy4S) is currently in trigger CCS_AS400_Integration, therefore it cannot recursively update itself: [] Trigger.CCS_AS400_Line_Import: line 17, column 1: [] Class.CCS_Line_Item_Manager.consolidateLineItems: line 138, column 1 Trigger.CCS_AS400_Integration: line 156, column 1

i have try to update trigger but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please post your code.

To prevent recursion, you can utilize a static variable to ensure that a specific functionality is executed only once. Begin by initializing the static boolean variable as "false." Then, within your code, implement a check to execute the functionality if the variable is "false"; subsequently, set the variable to "true" to mark it as executed. This way, the code will skip the functionality on subsequent calls.

In summary, the static variable acts as a flag to control whether the desired functionality has already been executed to prevent recursive calls.

example:

```
//Trigger
Trigger triggerName on Object (after update){
    if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isUpdate){
        triggerHandler.afterInsert(Trigger.oldMap,Trigger.newMap);
    }
}

// Recursion handler class
public class recursionClass{
     public static Boolean recursionVar = false;
}
//trigger handler
public class triggerHandler{
   public static void afterInsert(Map<Id,object> oldMap, Map<Id,object> newMap){
     if(!recursionClass.recursionVar){
        //your logic
         recursionClass.recursionVar =true;
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for getting answer for me. i have modify the trigger and stop recurring.